# What is the best way to define URLs / routes in Dropwizard?

Tags: java, jax-rs, dropwizard

Coming from frameworks like Django, I've found Dropwizard's URL handling involves lots of hardcoded routes:

```
@Path("/home")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class HomeResource { ... }

...
return Response.seeOther(URI.create("/home")).build();
...

...
<a href="/home">Home</a>   
...
```

What's the best way to move the declaration of routes to one place, so I can reference them by name from elsewhere in my app, including templates? This includes routes like `/profile/{user_id}` that require arguments.

Comment: You can use [`UriBuilder.fromResource(HomeResource.class).build()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#fromResource-java.lang.Class-) to get the URI from home

Comment: @peeskillet Is there any way to use this in templates?

Comment: You can use `resolveTemplate("user_id", theId)`. I'm not familiar with Django, so I'm not quite sure the exact functionality you're looking for. But `UriBuilder` is a good API to use for manipulating URIs

Comment: Annotations also take constants, if that makes it any easier for you. For example `@Path(Paths.PROFILE_USER_ID)`

Comment: @peeskillet That might be a better approach, I'll have a play around

Comment: You could find some general information about this topic in [this chapter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#resource-builder) of `Jersey`'s documentation. `JAX-RS` approach is chosen to be annotation-driven/declarative.  Dropwizard is using `Jersey` for the `JAX-RS` stuff.